# EOL while scanning string literal even when it is closed

Tags: python

on the line path = bla bla at the end of it it says EOL while scanning string literal even though it is closed of with '' I have this happend alot to me in my codes and its really annoying because i can never fix it.

```
import os
import shutil


'''VVV THIS LINE HERE IS SAY THIS     VVV <--- here until the end of the screen '''
path = '\C:\Users\jyelo\Desktop\Test\'
names = os.listdir(path)
folder_name = ['PNG', 'JFIF']

for x in range(0,2):
    if not os.path.exists(path+folder_name[x]):
        os.makedirs(path+folder_name[x])

for files in names:
    if ".png" in files and not os.path.exists(path+'PNG/'+files):
        shutil.move(path+files, path+'PNG/'+files)
    if ".jfif" in files and not os.path.exists(path+'JFIF/'+files):
    shutil.move(path+files, path+'JFIF/'+files)
```

Comment: update path to `r"C:\Users\jyelo\Desktop\Test"`

Comment: [@zamir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9256761/zamir): This is technically a good solution, but would break his entire code because everywhere he assumes `path` has a trailing slash so would requires a lot more changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
path = '\C:\Users\jyelo\Desktop\Test\'
```

Should be:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\jyelo\\Desktop\\Test\\'
```

More info: [String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Error part:
    \'
The backslash. You can't use backslash here. It has some special meanings like '\n', '\t', '\r', etc.

You can also see the highlights of your code. After the error part every text is in orange color and that's an error sign.